# Pass command line Params in mvn exec:exec

Tags: maven-plugin

I am amazed that what should have been a very easy job is turning into a very annoying task for me. All i need is to pass few command line parameters to my maven exec:exec plugin. unfortunately hours of googling has not helped at all.

Here is my plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring.version}/spring-instrument-${spring.version}.jar</argument>
            <argument>-Xmx256m</argument>
            <argument>com.myPackage.Myclass</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now from the command prompt i am typing in:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args=-Dmy.property=myProperty
```

I also tried:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.arguments=-Dmy.property=myProperty
```

And many other things. However nothing seems to be working. I know that exec:exec runs in a separate VM but as per the documentation -Dexec.args should work for me. Can someone please suggest where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to get JVM args working for exec:exec using the following after reading [this article](http://redstack.wordpress.com/2010/12/22/configuring-maven-to-run-your-java-application/):

```xml
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.example.com</argument>
                    <argument>-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080</argument>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                    <classpath />
                    <argument>com.example.Main</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 38):

Two ways to pass command line arguments into mvn:exec:

Method 1, on the command line:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.myPackage.myClass" -Dexec.args="command line arguments"
```

Method 2, in the maven POM file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.myPackage.myClass</mainClass>
        <commandlineArgs>command line arguments</commandlineArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then on the command line all you have to do is run:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Good luck.

Comment: Finally, the example of working command line way. The problem is that official documentation for this plugin specifies [`commandlineArgs`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#commandlineArgs) property while the fact is that it is **`args`** instead.

Comment: The goal documentation specifies the Maven property and the bound user property in the same table. The mojo docs are a bit special to read but since they are automatically generated they are pretty correct (for the version they are produced for)

Answer (score 5):

why not use system property?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>bobo.Abc</mainClass>
                  <arguments>
                        <argument>argument1</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>jvmProperty1</key>
                            <value>dev</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command line setting to pass arguements to my Main-Class with the exceution plugin.

```
mvn clean install -Dexec.arguments="arg0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the selected answer solves the problem. Here is my somewhat hacky solution that works:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath />
            <argument>-Xmx256m</argument>
            <argument>com.myPackage.Myclass</argument>
            <argument>${myProperty1}</argument> <!-- variable args here!!! -->
            <argument>${myProperty2}</argument>

        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>myExecution</id> <!-- defined an id here! -->
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now you can simply execute passing the arguments.

```
mvn exec:exec@myExecution -DmyProperty1=XXX -DmyProperty2=YYY
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass command line arguments to Java VM use `<commandlineArgs>` tag instead of `<arguments>`. [Maven Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#commandlineArgs)

Cheers

Comment: AFAIK this is incorrect.  `<commandlineArgs>` overrides anything you set in the `<arguments>` list; they serve the same purpose.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `-Dexec.args` on the command line and it overrides the `<arguments>` given in `pom.xml`. You can use either of them, not both.